# how do get id in block magento2?

Tags: admin, magento2, blocks, static-block

in magento2 Admin `cms/page` i have call like,

```
{{block class="Mageaddons\Slideshow\Block\Slideshow" template="slideshow.phtml" slideshow_id="1"}}
```

but in block i run `$this->getData('slideshow_id');` is null.
what wrong?

Comment: try this : $block->getData('slideshow_id');

Answer (score 2):

Try this

CMS Page Content:

```
{{block class="Mageaddons\\Slideshow\\Block\\Slideshow"" template="your_folder_path/slideshow.phtml" }}
```

In phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```